# How to make curve border using css

Tags: javascript, css

How to make curve border like the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGTDw.png) using css? Thanks.
[image]

Comment: We may not create like as you provided image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [svg](/questions/tagged/svg)  [`polyline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/polyline) element.

Here is an example:

```css
.contain-demo {
    margin: 25px auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.p {
    text-align: center;
     margin-top: 140px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contain-demo">
   <svg width="150" height="200">
     <desc>First orange polyline demonstrating white fill on open path.</desc>
     <polyline points="0,40 40,40 40,80 80,80 80,120 120,120 120,160" fill="white" stroke="#D07735" stroke-width="6" />
   </svg>
   <svg width="150" height="200">
       <desc>Second orange polyline demonstrating yellow fill on open path.</desc>
       <polyline points="0,40 40,40 40,80 80,80 80,120 120,120 120,160" fill="#F9F38C" stroke="#D07735" stroke-width="6" />
   </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice approach, but please note that svg is not part of html, so `polyline` is an svg element, not an html element.

Comment: Ok, I learned something! :) I will change it soon.