# How to draw a gradient colored trapezoid with css3?

Tags: html, css

I need to make a trapezoid like in image, but I don't know how.

I'm trying to do it with the following css but I'm stuck:

```
#trapezoid {
    width: 100px;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid #82E81B;
    border-left: 0px solid transparent;
    border-right: 30px solid transparent;
}
```

If you have a good method to achieve using CSS it please tell me.

[image: 1]]

Comment: this is not only gradient, some 3d transformation must take place here. It is hard to just *make* it without known angles and sizes.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39697859/4575054) can help you to make the trapezoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look this:

```css
#div1 {
    position: relative;
    height: 150px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 50px;
    padding: 0px;
    -webkit-perspective: 150px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera  */
    perspective: 200px;
}

#div2 {
    padding: 40px 70px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius:2px;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-30deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera  */
    transform: rotateY(-30deg);

    box-shadow:3px 0px 6px rgb(19,83,60),inset 1px 1px 2px 2px rgba(241,251,50,1);
 background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #b7f915, #b7f915,#6fd00c);
  background-image:linear-gradient(to right,#b7f915,#b7f915, #6fd00c);
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is just great! Thanks!

Comment: Awesome idea using an inset shadow for rim light. And it even works with text inside

Answer (score 1):

Leaving the shadow and gradient to you. Enjoy.

```css
#trapezoid { 
  border-top: 50px solid #82E81B;
  border-left: 0px solid transparent; 
  border-right: 30px solid transparent; 
  height: 30px;
  background: transparent;
  width: 100px;
  perspective-origin: 0% 50%;
  transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -45deg );
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="trapezoid"></div>
```